# How to run Python script on files in Google Cloud

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a bunch of files in a Google Cloud Storage bucket, including some Python scripts and text files. I want to run the Python scripts on the text files. What would be the best way to go about doing this (App Engine, Compute Engine, Jupyter)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using Google Cloud Function, that can be triggered automatically each time you upload new file to the Cloud Storage to process it. You can see workflow for this in  [Cloud Function Storage Tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/storage)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to at least download the python scripts onto an environment first (be it GCE or GAE). To access the GCS text files, you can use https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-storage/ library. I don't think you can execute python scripts from the object bucket itself.

If it is troublesome to change the python codes for reading the text files from GCS, you will have to download everything into your environment (e.g. using gsutil)